Terraform Role Assignment Issues for Azure Function with Microsoft Sentinel Reader and Storage Blob Data Contributor
I am trying to deploy AzureRM built-in roles: Microsoft Sentinel Reader and Storage Blob Data Contributor using Terraform.
Problem:
The built-in roles are not being associated with the object ID belonging to the Azure Function. Consequently, the Azure Function is not getting the Microsoft Sentinel Reader role on the Log Analytics Workspace nor the Storage Blob Data Contributor role on the Storage Account.
I have tried specifying the resource IDs of the Log Analytics Workspace and the Storage Account in plain text next to the scope argument, but the issue persists. Terraform plan and apply complete without errors, and the object ID of the system-assigned identity belonging to the Azure Function is correct.
I am using the following documentation: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/role_assignment
Terraform Code with sensitive data removed:
# Role Assignment for the managed identity to access the storage account - Storage Blob Data Contributor
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "storage_account_access" {
  scope                = data.azurerm_storage_account.example_sa.id
  role_definition_name = "Storage Blob Data Contributor" # Assign the appropriate role for accessing blob data
  principal_id         = data.azurerm_windows_function_app.example_function.identity[0].principal_id
}

# Role Assignment for the managed identity to access the log analytics workspace - Microsoft Sentinel Reader
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "log_analytics_reader" {
  scope                = data.azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.example_la.id
  role_definition_name = "Microsoft Sentinel Reader" # Assign the appropriate role for accessing log analytics data
  principal_id         = data.azurerm_windows_function_app.example_function.identity[0].principal_id
}


# Data block for Windows Function App
data "azurerm_windows_function_app" "example_function" {
  name                = "example_function"
  resource_group_name = "example_rg"
}

# Log Analytics Workspace resource ID
data "azurerm_log_analytics_workspace" "example_la" {
  name                = "example_la"
  resource_group_name = "example_rg"
}

output "log_analytics_workspace_id" {
  value = data.azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.example_la.id
}

# Storage Account resource ID
data "azurerm_storage_account" "example_sa" {
  name                = "example_sa"
  resource_group_name = "example_rg"
}

output "storage_account_id" {
  value = data.azurerm_storage_account.example_sa.id
}


There are reasons not to assign the role to the Function App identity. Please check the following steps.

Make sure to check the Function App principal ID using the output block to verify if it is fetching the correct ID.
Ensure you have the Owner role or User Access Administrator role to give access.
Sometimes it will take time to reflect in the portal.

Here is the code to assign the role to Function app identity with output blocks.
    provider "azurerm" {
      features {}
    }
    
    data "azurerm_windows_function_app" "example_function" {
      name                = "venkat-app"
      resource_group_name = "Venkat"
    }
    
    data "azurerm_storage_account" "example_sa" {
      name                = "venkat8a43"
      resource_group_name = "Venkat"
    }
    
    data "azurerm_log_analytics_workspace" "example_la" {
      name                = "venkat-law"
      resource_group_name = "venkat"
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "storage_account_access" {
      scope                = data.azurerm_storage_account.example_sa.id
      role_definition_name = "Storage Blob Data Contributor"
      principal_id         = data.azurerm_windows_function_app.example_function.identity[0].principal_id
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "log_analytics_reader" {
      scope                = data.azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.example_la.id
      role_definition_name = "Microsoft Sentinel Reader"
      principal_id         = data.azurerm_windows_function_app.example_function.identity[0].principal_id
    }
    
    output "azurerm_windows_function_apps" {
      value = data.azurerm_windows_function_app.example_function.identity[0].principal_id
    }
    
    output "azurerm_role_assignments" {
      value = azurerm_role_assignment.storage_account_access
    }
    
    output "azurerm_role_assignment" {
      value = azurerm_role_assignment.log_analytics_reader
    }


Azure Function Identity:

Output:

Storage Blob data contributor role has been assigned successfully.

Microsoft Sentinel Reader role has been assigned successfully.

